# How to obtain code_hash, contract address, etc, when unit testing an ink smart contract?

Tags: ink, testing

I've been unit testing an ink smart contract by calling the constructor and testing various methods on the smart contract.

However, I now need to obtain the account of the contract in order to set its balance for testing purposes. How can I do this?

Lots of methods, such as getting/setting the current balance, code hash, etc, require the address of the contract.

What I've tried already:

a)

```
let mut contract = MyContract::default();
let code_hash = contract.env().own_code_hash(); // cannot access .env()
```

b)

```
let mut contract = MyContract::default();
let contract_addr = ink::env::account_id::<ink::env::DefaultEnvironment>(contract); // doesn't accept the contract as a parameter
```

c)

```
let mut contract = MyContract::default();
let contract_addr = ink::env::account_id::<ink::env::DefaultEnvironment>(); // using it correctly, but always returns the account [1, 1, 1, ... , 1]

let mut contract2 = MyContract::default();
let contract_addr2 = ink::env::account_id::<ink::env::DefaultEnvironment>(); // returns the account [1, 1, 1, ... , 1] again, the two contracts can't have the same address!
```

Essentially, I need access to the `.env()` in the unit tests somehow. Not sure how to do this or if this is the correct way to be doing it.

Comment: [here](https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_env/test/index.html#functions) are the function where you can set caller, calle or contract

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the following snippet to obtain contract address:

```rust
use ink::codegen::Env;
let mut contract = MyContract::default(); // init
let address = contract.env().account_id();
```

You can similarly access other EnvAccess methods whose implementation is provided for off-chain environment. `code_hash()` & `own_code_hash()` is not one of them though!

**Disclaimer:** You need to manually set the callee before initialising a contract otherwise your contract address will be same as last set callee (which is by default [1;32]). Below is a sample implementation on how to do it.

```rust
let contract_addr: AccountId = AccountId::from([0xFF as u8; 32]);  
set_callee::<DefaultEnvironment>(contract_addr);
let mut contract = MyContract::default();

assert_eq!(contract.env().account_id(), contract_addr); // true
```

Comment: Thanks, the `use ink::codegen::Env;` was what I was missing